# Jquery Chosen Add dynamically Option

Tags: jquery

I working about input name select box using jquery plugin (chosen)

In my working restriction

1. Input a element in the input type=text element (using chosen plugin select box) <- OK
2. Input a input type=text element to selected user name from popup window. <- Can't!

I want to adding dynamically option in select box.

So, I was added element into a children node of chosen-choices;

This is my HTML Code

```
 <select data-placeholder="Please enter your name" class="chosen-select chosen_member2" multiple style="min-width:400px;width:auto;float:left;height: 30px;" tabindex="4">
                            </select>
```

This is my Jquery Code

```
$(".chosen-choices").eq(0).find(".search-field").before("<li class=\"search-choice\"><span>"+uname+" (Executive Dept)</span><a class=\"search-choice-close\" data-option-array-index=\""+auto_num+"\"></a></li>");
```

`$('.chosen-choices').eq(0).trigger("chosen:updated");`

And, Successfully Adding Option Element.

if adding a option element into a Selectbox, One of the Dropdown Items is inactive.

but, In my Case, adding a element into a select, One of the Dropdown Items is active.

Therefore!,

Although adding a element, Option Element is active as ever.
(i need to inactive option when i adding a input type=text element into a chosen-choices class)

Answer (score 0):

I hope there is no possibility in chosen, So try select2

http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/